# How to use unique child dependency version from parent in maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a long list of modules getting properties from a parent module in maven. I want one of the modules to use a different version of spring from the parent. The other modules are using an older version of spring which will not work with module-c.

Is there a way to make the child module use its own version of spring?

// Parent

```
<groupId>xxx.xx.com</groupId>
   <artifactId>test-environment</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <name>test-environment</name>

  <properties>
       <spring.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

    <modules>
     <module>module-a</module>
     <module>module-b</module>
     <module>module-c</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

//Child

```
<project>

<parent>
    <groupId>xxx.xx.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-environment</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>module-c</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

//Error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forInstance(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/core/ResolvableType;
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.resolveDefaultEventType(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.started(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149)
```

Comment: Does your parent pom has `<dependencyManagement>` section with `spring-context` declared in it?

Comment: @SergeyProkofiev No it does not have <dependencyManagement>

Answer (score 1):

Your approach with declaring newer dependency directly in the child `pom.xml` is correct. As per [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management):

> Dependency mediation - this determines what version of an artifact will be chosen when multiple versions are encountered as dependencies. Maven picks the "nearest definition". That is, it uses the version of the closest dependency to your project in the tree of dependencies. You can always guarantee a version by declaring it explicitly in your project's POM.

You most likely need to add `spring-core` on which the `spring-context` depends to have the right version of `org.springframework.core.ResolvableType` class and avoid `NoSuchMethodError`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Running with multiple version of Spring in the classpath is asking for runtime problems. It's best to keep all the Spring JARs in the same version in your runtime deployment.

Comment: thanks i had to add the a whole bunch of spring dependencies to make it work. Just one question, if i upgrade the parent spring version from 4.0.6.RELEASE to 4.3.0.RELEASE to affect all child modules will it not break other modules which are currently on 4.0.6.RELEASE. Won't i run into compatibility issues? The child modules are quite plenty about 20 of them so i had decided to go the cautious route of using the 4.3.0.RELEASE on one module only.